# resolve a NewtonSoft dependency in a NET4.0 project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I have a project, let's say project A. It is a dll (Class Library) project. The target framework is .NET 4.0 (not client profile). I added to this project the nugget for Azure Storage, which itself added a bunch of other references. The project build without problem.

In the same solution, I have another project, let's say project B. The project B is also a dll (Class Library) project. The target framework is also .NET 4.0 (not client profile). It also has a bunch of references to other libraries, but by itself, it builds fine.

The problem arises when I add a reference to project A in project B. It than doesn't compile anymore, and the root of the problem is I think, related to a serie of these warning at the beginning of the compilation

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3275: The primary reference "..." could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

Project B actually uses JSON NewtonSoft 4.5.0.0 at many places, but I understand that the Azure nugget needs JSON NewtonSoft 6.0. What I don't understand is why the project A is compiling correctly in NET4.0 but generates an error when linked in project B.

I need to keep using NewtonSoft 4.5.0.0 in project B (it's impossible for me to upgrade project B to JSON NewtonSoft 6.0).

It is also impossible for me to upgrade to NET4.5

I found in ...\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.8\lib some folder with net45 dll of Newtonsoft and deleted them before rebuilding, to no aval.

Comment: This is not supposed to happen, and doesn't when I check it, the one copied to the project's build directory is certainly the one that came from the lib\net40 directory.  You'll need to post project A's detailed build trace to get a possibly reason.

Comment: With pleasure. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying problem that Visual Studio creates by itself.

Long story short:

- Visual studio finds a dependency that needs to add to your 'bin' in order for your application to work
- The first dll that he finds in ANY of the bin folders of your project solutions it's used
- If the first DLL found does not match the version, it throws this error at compile time

How I've solved this:

- Find all DLL's with the wrong version (right click -> properties) in all projects and delete them, leaving only the DLL with the correct version
- Cleanup and rebuild

Another way of solving this:

- Use nuget to update the dependency: it will use the newest version and replace all your dependencies in all projects, allowing to compile

Comment: If I use nugget to update the dependency in project B, will I still be able to use NewtonSoft 4.5.0.0 in it ?

Comment: so you need to use BOTH versions in different projects?? :O

Comment: Well, maybe I was not clear in my question. I cannot change the NewtonSoft version project B is using (4.5.0.0, it's already precompiled in another folder, switching to another version could break stuff, I was forbidden to do it). Project A however needs NewtonSoft 6.0.0.0 (this one is updated by the nugget, so no problem there).

Comment: BTW, as said in my question, I already deleted all the dll with the wrong version and rebuilded. It didn't worked.